# Font color for parameter / variable type

Tags: visual-studio, editor, color-scheme

In Visual Studio (we are using 2013 Professional with Update 5 for programming in C#), type names of parameters and variables are shown in different colors depending on their type, e.g.

```
string aString;
String anotherString;
```

Is it possible to change the color of "string" to the color of "String"?
If it's not possible with VS itself, how can that be done with ReSharper?

In Visual Studio, I go to Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors. An enormous number is available, but which pair do I have to pick for this purpose? (Note: only this single one setting should be changed, other settings must not be changed.)

(Making my colleagues happy can be a demanding job...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't change the colors *only* for the String/string keywords, but the color to change for `string` is "Keyword", and for `String` "UserTypes - Classes". However, this also affects all other keywords and classes.